# matching opening and closing braces in emacs

Tags: emacs, gnu

I am a newbie to emacs and have been using it only for a month.
My queries are:

1. I want to track the matching opening and closing braces in the editor. Is there a command for this?
2. When trying to use emacs using cygwin in Windows, C-x C-c to close emacs does not work!
   Is there a way I can get this to work?

Comment: This may be better on the superuser stack exchange forum.

Comment: Don't ask unrelated questions together. Edit out the second question, and post it separately. Make sure you accept an answer if you're happy (I see you've commented "problem solved", but not accepted either answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like [`mic-paren`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MicParen), which has many options for customizing how to show matching parentheses, including showing you the line of the matching paren in the minibuffer when it is off-screen.

I set it up as follows:

```
(setq paren-dont-touch-blink t)
(require 'mic-paren)
(paren-activate)
(setq paren-match-face 'highlight)
(setq paren-sexp-mode t)
```

Comment: Looks interesting. The only thing it doesn't appear to do is the one thing that highlight-parentheses mode does. That is, show the matching parens enclosing point, color-coded. This makes it really easy to see where you are in deeply nested code. Or lisp. Can you make mic-paren do that? I'm guessing turning on two advanced paren modes at the same time might lead to interesting conflicts.

Comment: Can anyone help me on the emacs command on cygwin problem given above? Thanks.

Comment: @Tyler mic-paren doesn't have the functionality of showing all the enclosing parentheses, it doesn't really fit with the feature of showing a message for the matching paren...  To easily navigate up nested parens, try `M-x backward-up-list` and `M-x backward-down-list`.

Comment: @TreyJackson : Thanks. Please give me the key sequence for backward-up-list and backward-down-list.

Comment: @Indrani_Gorti to find where things are bound, `C-h w backward-up-list` - which shows: `backward-up-list is on <C-M-up>, C-M-u, ESC <C-up>`.  Similar for down.

Answer (score 1):

[show-paren-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Matching.html) will highlight matching parentheses, at least when the cursor is on one or the other.

A more powerful alternative is [highlight parentheses mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightParentheses). This will highlight all the parentheses around point (the cursor), so you see the scope of all the enclosing parentheses as you navigate your code.

There are other options as well, listed on the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryParentheses).

Comment: Thanks Trey and Tyler.  I tried both mic-paren and highlight parentheses mode. Problem solved :)                                         -Indrani Gorti